# Sufficient conditions for two ideals with the same zero set to be equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a one-dimensional noetherian ring finite over $k[x]$. Let $I$, $J$ be two integral ideals of $R$ with $J \subseteq I$ and $I$ invertible. Moreover, assume that $V(I) = V(J)$.

> What are sufficient conditions for $I = J$?

---

**What I tried:**

From $V(I) = V(J)$ one concludes $\operatorname{Rad}(J) = \operatorname{Rad}(I)$ and thus there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$I^n \subseteq J \subseteq I.$$

Until now I did not use the 'invertible'-assumption on $I$. From that it follows at least that $V(I)$ and a fortiori $V(J)$ is finite. It also follows that $I \cap k[x] = fk[x] \neq 0$.

I appreciate any kind of help or idea.

---

**Edit:** You may also assume that $f \in J$ and hence $J \cap k[x] = I \cap k[x]$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'integral ideals'?

Comment: @MarcPaul Ideals contained in $R$ in contrast to fractional ideals.

Comment: What kind of condition are you looking for? E.g., if $R$ is normal, you're really only fixing the support of the divisor; the coefficients can be whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to characterize elements that generate $I$ in terms of having zeros **relative to $I$** as follows:

We say that **$f \in I$ has a zero $\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ relative to $I$** if $f \in \mathfrak{m}I$.

Then we obtain the following

> **Lemma**:
>   Let $I \subset R$ be an invertible ideal and let $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in I$. Then
>   $$\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle = I \quad\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad\quad f_1,\ldots,f_n\ \ \text{ do not share a common zero relative to }I.$$

$\ \ $**Proof:**
Let $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle = I$ and assume there is $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in \mathfrak{m}I$, then $R = \langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle I^{-1} \subset \mathfrak{m}$; a contradiction!

Conversely, let $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ don't have any common zero relative to $I$, that is for all $\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ we have $$\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle \not \subset \mathfrak{m}I \quad\Rightarrow\quad \langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle I^{-1} \not \subset \mathfrak{m}$$
and thus $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle I^{-1}$ is an integral ideal not contained in any prime ideal and therefore it must be equal to $R$, hence $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle = I$.